# Access Control List of Google Cloud Storage for huge number of users

Tags: google-cloud-storage, access-control

I am storing images of one user(owner) in google cloud storage bucket. I wanted to grant read permission for this image to a group of users(contacts of owner).I am planning to use Access Control List for this purpose; e.g., Owner will have full permission to his bucket and the contacts will have read permission on the images. There are chances that owner will have a very huge number of contacts, say 1 million.
So,
will there be any performance issue, if ACL contains a huge number of users?
Will this be the right approach for access control? Or should I consider signed URL?

Regards,Remya

Answer (score 1):

This approach is not going to work for you. There are some significant limitations and downsides to trying to serve content like this. First and foremost, there is a [limit of 100 ACL entries](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#About-Access-Control-Lists) on a given object. You could get around this by granting permission to a group for which every user was a member, but even so, it still means that viewing the images will require that every user be logged in to their Google account in addition to however they authenticate for your site.

The canonical way to accomplish this would be to keep all images private and owned by your site's own account. When a user loads a page, verify however you like that they have appropriate authorization to view the images, and if so, [generate signed URLs for the images](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control?hl=en#Signed-URLs). This allows you to use any authorization scheme without limitation while serving images directly from GCS.